# How can disable a foreign key and then rollback in Oracle database from stored procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-update, rollback

I am working on an Oracle sql database.
I have a stored procedure where I need to update the value of the primary key in a table.
That value is referenced by a foreign key from another table.

I can disable that foreign key constraint,then perform the update and then enable it back and this works.

The problem is that if something goes wrong after altering the foreign key status I cannot rollback prior to the update.

To resume:

1. UPDATE
2. ALTER FOREIGN KEY
3. ROLLBACK

Is there any way I can rollback to the state before performing the update and if yes then how ?

Thanks.

Comment: do you have any scope to change the structure of the database? As soon as you say "I need to update the value of the pk" alarm bells started ringing.

Comment: Disabling the Foreign Key and then updating the table almost immediately defeats the purpose of the Foreign key. Why have the foreign key at all, unless you are doing some kind of data conversion or mass load.

Comment: Indeed, alarm bells start ringing. But this table has a primary key that also refferences another primary key from another table. ( Sound fun , no ?! :) ) And now, because some ids in the base table have become obsolete I need to update the ids in the child table.

Comment: What problems are causing you to want to rollback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately not. ALTER TABLE is a DDL command, and DDL statements cannot be `ROLLBACK`ed. So you cannot rollback before this command.

Solution for you could be to change foreign key to deffered validation. You can then change the primary key and foreign key using two updates in ona transaction. Constraint will be validated at next commit.

Comment: Correct verbiage should be - `DDL statements cannot be ROLLBACKed`. There is no auto-commit for DDL.

Comment: @Annjawn - not sure I agree with that change; from [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10713/transact.htm#sthref1318): "The database issues an implicit COMMIT statement before and after every DDL statement". It's not just that the DDL can't be rolled back, any DML prior to that in the transaction is committed too. (Though I agree 'auto commit' doesn't sound right either).

Comment: Yes, `implicit commit` sounds right. The change I did says that DDL statements cannot be rollbacked. An isolated DML statement can always be rollbacked, unless ofcourse you forget to do so and then happen to run a DDL statement.

Comment: Nits: 1) DDL can, and will, be rolled back when the database encounters an error while performing the DDL statement itself. The limitation is on us at the SQL or PL/SQL level not being able to rollback DDL after the statement has completed. 2) Some clients and drivers will send a commit statement after each DML statement. This is another exception to the general statement that you can rollback until commit or DDL.